# <EDITED> Python 2.7 tkinter (and IDLE) "problems"

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-idle

I got some tkinter-based problems when I used the Python IDLE.

### First, IDLE couldn't be opened in my computer

I use Python 2.7.12.

After openning IDLE through the windows command line, I've found where the problem is.

It's in Tkinter:

```
###C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py
##Line:80
value = unicode(value, 'utf-8')
```

This failed with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 80, in _stringify
    value = unicode(value, 'utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

So I changed it to:

```
###C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py
##Line:80
value = unicode(value, 'cp950')
```

Then it works fine now, but does everyone have to modify their IDLE before using it?

Is this kind of a bug?

### Second, my friend couldn't change IDLE's font size

Here is my debug note:

```
    ###C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py
##Ln:10
import idlelib.PyShell
idlelib.PyShell.main()

###C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py
##Ln:1475
def main():
    global flist, root, use_subprocess
##Ln:1552 in function main
    # start editor and/or shell windows:
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
    root.withdraw()
##Ln:1570 in function main
    flist = PyShellFileList(root)
##Ln:312
class PyShellFileList(FileList):
    "Extend base class: IDLE supports a shell and breakpoints"

    # override FileList's class variable, instances return PyShellEditorWindow
    # instead of EditorWindow when new edit windows are created.
    EditorWindow = PyShellEditorWindow

###C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\FileList.py
##Ln:6
class FileList:

    # N.B. this import overridden in PyShellFileList.
    from idlelib.EditorWindow import EditorWindow

###C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py
##Ln:125
class PyShellEditorWindow(EditorWindow):
    "Regular text edit window in IDLE, supports breakpoints"

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.breakpoints = []
        EditorWindow.__init__(self, *args)

###C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py
##Ln:262 in class EditorWindow
    text['font'] = idleConf.GetFont(self.root, 'main', 'EditorWindow')

###C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\configHandler.py
##Ln:700 in class IdleConf
    def GetFont(self, root, configType, section):
        """Retrieve a font from configuration (font, font-size, font-bold)
        Intercept the special value 'TkFixedFont' and substitute
        the actual font, factoring in some tweaks if needed for
        appearance sakes.

        The 'root' parameter can normally be any valid Tkinter widget.

        Return a tuple (family, size, weight) suitable for passing
        to tkinter.Font
        """
        family = self.GetOption(configType, section, 'font', default='courier')
        size = self.GetOption(configType, section, 'font-size', type='int',
                              default='10')
        bold = self.GetOption(configType, section, 'font-bold', default=0,
                              type='bool')
        if (family == 'TkFixedFont'):
            if TkVersion < 8.5:
                family = 'Courier'
            else:
                f = Font(name='TkFixedFont', exists=True, root=root)
                actualFont = Font.actual(f)
                family = actualFont['family']
                size = actualFont['size']
                if size <= 0:
                    size = 10  # if font in pixels, ignore actual size
                bold = actualFont['weight']=='bold'
        return (family, size, 'bold' if bold else 'normal')

###C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\tkFont.py
##Ln:66 in class Font
    def __init__(self, root=None, font=None, name=None, exists=False, **options):
        if not root:
            root = Tkinter._default_root
        tk = getattr(root, 'tk', root)
##Ln:92 in class Font in method __init__
        self._split = tk.splitlist
        self._call  = tk.call
##Ln:120 in class Font
    def actual(self, option=None):
        "Return actual font attributes"
        if option:
            return self._call("font", "actual", self.name, "-"+option)
        else:
            return self._mkdict(
                self._split(self._call("font", "actual", self.name))
                )
##Ln:60 in class Font
    def _mkdict(self, args):
        options = {}
        for i in range(0, len(args), 2):
            options[args[i][1:]] = args[i+1]
        return options
```

So the problem is Tkinter ...again. I ran a small test:

```
import Tkinter
root=Tkinter.Tk()
def _mkdict(args):
    options = {}
    for i in range(0, len(args), 2):
        options[args[i][1:]] = args[i+1]
    return options
resulta=_mkdict(root.tk.splitlist(root.tk.call("font","actual","TkFixedFont")))
print "a",resulta
resultb=_mkdict(root.tk.splitlist(root.tk.call("font","actual","細明體")))
print "b",resultb
```

Then I got:

```
a {'family': u'\u7d30\u660e\u9ad4', 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0, 'size': 10}
b {'family': u'\u65b0\u7d30\u660e\u9ad4', 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0, 'size': 15}
```

So the problem is in tkFont.Font's actual module? Or...?

### Edit

Maybe I didn't describe the second "problem" very well, maybe I gave too much details, so here's the core of the second problem:

```
###C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\configHandler.py
##Ln:700 in class IdleConf
def GetFont(self, root, configType, section):
    """Retrieve a font from configuration (font, font-size, font-bold)
    Intercept the special value 'TkFixedFont' and substitute
    the actual font, factoring in some tweaks if needed for
    appearance sakes.

    The 'root' parameter can normally be any valid Tkinter widget.

    Return a tuple (family, size, weight) suitable for passing
    to tkinter.Font
    """
    family = self.GetOption(configType, section, 'font', default='courier')
    size = self.GetOption(configType, section, 'font-size', type='int',
                          default='10')
    bold = self.GetOption(configType, section, 'font-bold', default=0,
                          type='bool')
    if (family == 'TkFixedFont'):
        if TkVersion < 8.5:
            family = 'Courier'
        else:
            f = Font(name='TkFixedFont', exists=True, root=root)
            actualFont = Font.actual(f)
            family = actualFont['family']
            size = actualFont['size']
            if size <= 0:
                size = 10  # if font in pixels, ignore actual size
            bold = actualFont['weight']=='bold'
    return (family, size, 'bold' if bold else 'normal')
```

If the font family is not "TkFixedFont", getFont will return the right size, which is configured by user at the "configure IDLE" panel.

But if the font family is "TkFixedFont", it'll ignore user's setting and use "actualFont['size']", which is 10, as I tested.

Comment: Why are you starting Idle from a Windows command line? It's a graphical program that should open its own window.

Comment: @Mark, IDLE does open it own window, but starting from command line provides a place for error messages to appear when there is a problem, especially with startup.

Answer (score 0):

As to the second issue, which I believe is unrelated to the first.  I don't really understand the question or the point of the code quotations.

IDLE has an Option settings dialog accessed through the menu.  The initial (and default) tab has a font size setting which has always worked for me (on Windows).  The answer to 'How to change fontsize?' is to use the intended font size change widget.

I just rechecked with 2.7.13 and it still works for me.  There was a bug in 2.7.11 that manifested as an inability to open the dialog on some Linux systems.  But that was fixed in 2.7.12.  I checked the 2.7.13 patch list and none should have affected font sizing.  Still, as far as IDLE goes, I would recommend upgrading.